# How can I filter the records and only get the max records with sql?

Tags: sql

Does anyone know how can I filter the records and only get the max records with sql?

Example:

If I have the following data in tableA

```
DIN         Title      FirstName       LastName     Phone         StNum     StName
A1111111    Mr         A               Scott        0412352145    1         Churct St
A2222222    Miss       C               Scott        0412352145    1         Churct St
A1111       Mr         B               Scott        0412352145    1         Churct St
```

How can I using the sql script to filter the record based on the same phone number and then only get the larger DIN record?

So the respecting return record is like the following:

```
DIN         Title      FirstName       LastName     Phone         StNum     StName
A2222222    Miss       C               Scott        0412352145    1         Churct St
```

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: What do you mean by 'larger DIN record'. Do you mean longest string or highest number following A or does DIN follow a pattern like A1111, B2222, C3333 etc and C333 is the largest because it is the latest alphabetically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common way of doing this is joining the table to itself using the `MAX` aggregate:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
   join (
       select phone, max(din) maxdin
       from yourtable
       group by phone
   ) t2 on t.phone = t2.phone and t.din = t2.maxdin
```

- [Reduced SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63e27/1)